# SeriesSelection gets null value if Bar Spacing is set to negative value in AChartEngine Android

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I am working on an android app and using AChartEngine for Charting. The Bar Chart is drawn on the basis of the dynamic data coming from a server. If there is only one bar is drawn its width is quite small and to make it more wide i applied the condition that in case of single bar, bar spacing is set to negative value so that it appears wider. On clicking the bar i was displaying a toast which gets the series value and point using AChartEngine built-in function like this.

```
SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
```

The bar spacing was set to be

`renderer.setBarSpacing(0.6f);` in case of multiple bars

`renderer.setBarSpacing(-1.5f);` in case of single bar.

Now on clicking the bar seriesSelection always gets null value hence no toast is displayed. if bar spacing is positive value then toast works fine even for single bar but the bar itself would be very thin. How to make the bar wider in case of single bar and fine working of toast?

Comment: This may be a bug, so the only choice could be that you post an issue on http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/